# apply lambda function after groupby based on values of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I made up a dataframe to illustrate my question. Say, I have three patients: 'a', 'b', 'c'. We got results from these patient at three different time points (t1, t2, t3). What I need is to create another column 'Fold', which is the fold change from t1. Since patient 'c' does not has any result at t1, its fold change vs t1 should be `nan`. 
Below is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({ \
                   'time': np.repeat(['t1','t2','t3'], [2,3,3]),
                   'id': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'result':np.random.randint(10,20,size=8) })
# create indicator column has_t1: if a patient  has t1: 1 if not: 0
df['is_t1'] = np.where(df['time']=='t1', 1, 0)
df['has_t1'] = df.groupby('id')['is_t1'].transform(sum)
# create fold change column
df['fold'] =df.sort_values(['id', 'time']).groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['result']/x['result'].iloc[0] if x['has_t1'].iloc[0]==1 else np.nan)
```

I got error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'index'
```

My desired output is something like:

```
        Fold
id time          
a  t1    1.000000
   t2    1.545455
   t3    1.000000
b  t1    1.000000
   t2    1.062500
   t3    0.937500
c  
   t2         NaN
   t3         NaN
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternate approach that does not involve an indicator column. First, `unstack` and then re-`stack` without dropping NaNs:

```
df = df.set_index(['id', 'time']).unstack().stack(dropna=False) 
df

         result
id time        
a  t1      12.0
   t2      18.0
   t3      13.0
b  t1      13.0
   t2      11.0
   t3      13.0
c  t1       NaN
   t2      13.0
   t3      17.0
```

Next, call `groupby` + `transform` + `head` and divide `df.result` by this output:

```
df['result'] /= df.groupby(level=0).result.transform('head', 1)    
df

           result
id time          
a  t1    1.000000
   t2    1.545455
   t3    1.000000
b  t1    1.000000
   t2    1.062500
   t3    0.937500
c  t1         NaN
   t2         NaN
   t3         NaN
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED thanks a lot!  This works. But I'm also curious about what I did wrong? Would you give some advice?

Comment: @zesla Your lambda wasn't written correctly. The lambda is called once per group. You wrote it in such a way that it would be called for each row per group... that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm , there is a another way

```
s=df.set_index(['id','time']).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([set(df.id.tolist()),set(df.time.tolist())]))

s=s.sort_index()
s.result.div(s.groupby(level=0).result.nth(0),level=0)
Out[256]: 
a  t1    1.000000
   t2    1.900000
   t3    1.800000
b  t1    1.000000
   t2    0.736842
   t3    0.578947
c  t1         NaN
   t2         NaN
   t3         NaN
Name: result, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I guess they want NaN for the entire C group :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way using groupby, apply and stack.

```
def fold(x):
    df_tmp = x.set_index('time')    
    df_tmp = df_tmp.reindex(df_tmp.index.union(['t1']))
    return df_tmp.result.div(df_tmp.loc['t1','result'])

df.groupby('id').apply(fold).stack(dropna=False)
Out[229]: 
id  result
a   t1        1.000000
    t2        0.923077
    t3        0.923077
b   t1        1.000000
    t2        1.300000
    t3        1.400000
c   t1             NaN
    t2             NaN
    t3             NaN
```